# How to ignore invites to a specific account in Apple Calendar?

Tags: macos, mac, calendar, google-calendar

I have both work and personal Google accounts/calendars set up w/ Apple Calendar on my mac. I want to see both calendars but I only want to see invites on my personal computer for my personal account, and not have to deal with buckets of work meeting invites.

Is there any way to do this?

M1 MBP running Big Sur